# I want to store and process pdf files in hdfs. Is it possible to write a custom serde for loading pdf files into hive?

Tags: pdf, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

1. Processing pdf files in HDFS using custom SERDE in hive.

Comment: what kind of processing do you want to do? If it's text analysis, you should just run the .pdfs through pdftotext.

Comment: nope. want to extract some specific info from the pdfs. Is it possible to write some custom I/p format, Rec reader and mapper to do that?

Comment: first figure out how you can your pdf processing in plain java (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java ). Then, write custom InputFormat and Load/Store functions

Comment: How did you store pdf files in hive? I meant what was the ddl and dml statements?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have the answer (and I believe that you found the answer), you can convert the pdf file into base64 and then save it as a string in Hive. I do not know the process part, but I believe that you can get this base64 string and then create a temp file to make your process algorithm work or send it into the PDF process backend and return the base64 bytes to you to store in your Hive database... Sorry for the late reply, but I saw your post only today.

And here, is some code:

The Encoder:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<List<int>> readPdfFileAsBytes(String filePath) async {
  final File file = File(filePath);
  return await file.readAsBytes();
}

String convertBytesToBase64(List<int> bytes) {
  return base64Encode(bytes);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final String pdfFilePath = 'path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf';

  // Read PDF file as bytes
  List<int> pdfBytes = await readPdfFileAsBytes(pdfFilePath);

  // Convert bytes to Base64
  String base64String = convertBytesToBase64(pdfBytes);

  // Output the Base64 encoded data
  print(base64String);
}
```

The Decoder:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

List<int> decodeBase64ToBytes(String base64String) {
  return base64Decode(base64String);
}

void writeBytesToPdfFile(List<int> bytes, String outputFilePath) {
  final File file = File(outputFilePath);
  file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
}

void main() {
  final String base64String = '...'; // Replace '...' with your Base64 encoded data
  final String outputFilePath = 'path/to/output/file.pdf';

  // Decode Base64 to bytes
  List<int> pdfBytes = decodeBase64ToBytes(base64String);

  // Write bytes to PDF file
  writeBytesToPdfFile(pdfBytes, outputFilePath);
}
```